# Mule SOAP generic config reference for implementing security

Tags: web-services, soap, mule, ws-security

Just tried with implementing WS Security in SOAP using **UsernameToken** in mule. It worked fine.
Now since i am using SOAP component at various locations in my mule project, i want to know if there is any way to define WS security parameter **globally** and then refer those properties in each SAOP component, without having to define them for each component. Such global WS security definitions should be used in various deployed mule packages.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "SOAP component"? Can you show your config? What Mule version?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a spring config file and import that in each application. Alternatively just use a properties file with your definitions.